# iOS8 UITableView with autolayout has a blank space above cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout, size-classes

I've created a UIViewController in a storyboard using autolayout and it has an embedded UITableView. For some reason there is white space above the table view section. My expectation is that the tableview would split all available space into cells and have cells starting right from the top.

**What is causing the table view to add empty space above the first section when using auto layout and size classes?**

(See screenshot below, the white space beneath "television" and above "Prototype cells" is the problem)
[image]

I've examined the constraints and insets, and cant see anything wrong with them: 
[image]

UPDATE:
Here's the scene hierarchy
[image]

Comment: can you post the scene hierarchy ?

Comment: Change y co-ordinate to y=64. it will solving your problem

Comment: I think when using autolayout the x,y coordinates you see are meaningless - they are adjusted by constraints at runtime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try toggling the UIViewController property in Interface Builder named:

```
Adjust Scroll View Insets
```

Answer (score 1):

If you drag a view into the table view it becomes the tableviews headerview that gives a space similar to what you see. Could this be the issue? Your posted layout looks correct.

Alternativley If you click on the Watch view controller in the hierarchy and switch in the simulated metrics section the top bar property from inferred to translucent navigation bar and back again this seems to move the cells down in the tableview when it is set to a translucent navigation bar

Comment: The tableview has no header, only 3 prototype cells

Comment: Im just playing arround trying to recreate the effect. If you click on the Watch view controller in the hierarchy and switch in the simulated metrics section the top bar property from inferred to translucent navigation bar and back again this seems to move the cells down in the tableview when it is set to a translucent navigation bar